# CSS3 animation to JQUERY fade out or disappear

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am attempting an animation in css3, in which I would like to use jQuery to fadeOut() at the end of the animation. After writing my code the transition does not work.

Here is my css3:

```
.slideRight{
    animation-name: slideRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideRight; 

    animation-duration: 3s; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;

    animation-timing-function: ease;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;        

    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(150%);
        }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(150%);
    }
}
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yacht').fadeTo(function(){
    $('#yacht').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!--Yacht-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <img src="images/yacht.png" class="img-responsive slideRight" id="yacht" alt="Picture of a Yacht" />
    </div>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the HTML too?

Comment: Looks like a syntax error `$('#yacht').fadeTo(function(){` This function fails to close properly.

Comment: `.fadeTo()` what??? Please read the DOC, you are missing some parameters. Or then, use `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the existing animation to fade out the image at the end of the animation? You can just set the opacity to start animating at like `90-95%` and set the `opacity` to `0` at `100%` of the animation:

```
@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    90% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-opacity: 1;
        -moz-opacity: 1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(150%);
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
        -moz-opacity: 0;
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
        display: none;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    90% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-opacity: 1;
        -moz-opacity: 1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(150%);
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
        -moz-opacity: 0;
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
        display: none;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JckdJ/3/

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yacht').fadeTo(function(){
    $('#yacht').css('display', 'none');
});
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yacht').fadeTo(function(){
       $('#yacht').css('display', 'none');
    }); <--- here
});
```

overall, I think you want to do something like this

```
var events = 'anomationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yacht').on(events, function(){
       $('#yacht').fadeOut();
    }); <--- here
});
```

This will happen when the animation ends, as your code progresses you may need to identify the animation before you execute the `fadeOut();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I fixed the syntax issue; however, it still doesn't fade out after animation.